# Use column in subquery, but not in the main query's select

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

First these are my tables:

```
 Foo (id, Name)
 Bar (foo_id, num)
```

I am trying to do the following: I want to select the Foos where all its Bars have a num higher than 10. The query below works perfectly fine and does that, but I don't want to have the Foo.id in the select. When I remove the Foo.id from the select, I get an error that the column is not found in the where clause (Of the subquery).

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'Foo.id' in 'where clause'
```

How can I remove the Foo.id from the select, but still use the column in the subquery's where clause? I tried joining the Foo table in the subquery and use Name in the where, but this does not give me the desired results as Name is not unique.

```
SELECT 
    Foo.Name, 
    Foo.id
FROM
    Foo
    LEFT  JOIN Bar ON Bar.foo_id = Foo.id
GROUP BY Bar.foo_id
HAVING COUNT(Bar.foo_id) = ( 
    SELECT 
        COUNT(Bar.foo_id) 
    FROM 
        Bar 
    WHERE 
        num > 10 
    AND 
        Bar.foo_id = Foo.id GROUP BY Bar.foo_id 
    )
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's another simple way,

```
SELECT  a.Name
FROM    Foo a
        INNER JOIN Bar b
            ON a.ID = b.foo_ID
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Name
HAVING  COUNT(b.foo_ID) = SUM(b.num > 10)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce7e9/2)

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved it, I never thought of comparing the sum of the amount of bar's that validate the condition to the count of the total joins.